# Synchronous vs asynchronous execution of an asynchronous promise returning function

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

When making asynchronous functions that return promises, in every implementation i've seen this practice:

```
function asyncFunction() {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  // the function code
  if (condition) resolve()
  else reject()
 })
}
```

In other words, the function code in the executor function is run synchronously, and only promise settling and and callback calling is done asynchronously. This has been counter-intuitive to me, because when I think of an asynchronous function, I think of a function that when it executes, returns immediately, and defers it's operations for later. Here is an example:

```
function asyncFunction() {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   // the function code
   if (condition) resolve()
   else reject()
  }, 0)
  
 })
}
```

This means that the code of the function will execute in a task, and all the callbacks registered on the returned promise will run as microtasks. The function returns immediately, and doesn't starve the thread.

I have a few questions now.

1. Is my reasoning correct/meaningful or I am not seeing some edge cases?
2. What characterizes an asynchronous function? I see two candidate parameters that characterize an asynchronous function: 1. returning immediately and running its computations later and 2. The callbacks run later/asynchronously. To me the only thing that characterizes such function is the first point, but as I see in all code I could find, the only thing that matters is that the callbacks are run async.
3. Is there any advantage/disadvantage of using my version of the code instead of the first one?

Comment: The first version of code is not actually a candidate for async function because it's not dependent upon something available in future.

Comment: Could you share an example with the synchronous implementation? It's indeed useless. Are you sure it wasn't onevent = resolve?

Comment: "*in every implementation i've seen this practice*" - please share some concrete examples. Is `// the function code` actually asynchronous?

Comment: In your second snippet, is there other code at `// the function code`? There shouldn't be. The asynchronous operation that the promise needs to wrap is only the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: "*What characterizes an asynchronous function?" - I don't see the difference between your two candidate descriptions. An async function always does return immediately *and* calls its callbacks later. It doesn't matter what happens in between, whether there are any computations or not (like in `setTimeout`).

Comment: @Bergi Maybe `in practice` was a bad way to put it, but I've seen many examples like the code above. Two I can think of, which are from a reputable source are these: 

https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_promises.html#implementing-a-promise-based-function

https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_promises.html#promise-based-functions-start-synchronously-settle-asynchronously

Comment: @Bergi `//function code` is not async. I don't quite understand this part: 'An async function always does return immediately *and calls its callbacks later. It doesn't matter what happens in between, whether there are any computations or not '. How does it not matter whether the function performs computations? The way I reason about async function is that it should perform the computations **after** when the stack only contains platform specific code. In some way, performing the computations **after** is what characterizes the function as async. May you elaborate on this more please? Thanks.

Comment: @LearningMath "*a Promise-based function that adds two numbers x and y*" is rubbish. It might be a quick example of how a promise can be constructed, but it's a bad example. This is synchronous code, which should not be wrapped in a promise at all.

Comment: @LearningMath "*How does it not matter whether the function performs computations?*" - because "performing computations" is a synchronous thing. What characterises an asynchronous function is that it **waits** for something, and it does that after having returned, concurrently. It might wait for a timeout, for some network packets be sent or received, for filesystem/disk operations, for an event to happen, or a background process to finish. (The background process might perform computations, but what makes a function asynchronous is only that it returns immediately and later calls a callback).

Answer (score 1):

Promises are tools to *manage* asynchronous code, not to make code asynchronous.

Your first example shouldn't use promises at all. Everything the function does is blocking. The use of a promise only adds complication. (The exception is if you are writing code to match an interface which is sometimes used for something asynchronous).

Your second example is also pointless (at least almost always). The timeout is being added *just* to let the event loop continue with something outside the function before picking it up again later. This *can* be useful (e.g. to allow the browser to repaint the window before doing something time consuming) but the approach should be:

1. I need to let the window be repainted before the next operation runs
2. I will run a timeout before that operation
3. I will use a Promise to manage that code

… whereas your code *seems* to be turning that upside and starting with a promise and trying to justify its use.

If you have some time-consuming code to run and you don't want it to block the main event loop then you should probably be using a *worker* so it runs on a different thread. Possibly you would use a Promise to handle that code sending its result back to the main event loop.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean about the second snippet, isn't exactly doing what you say it should be doing? And there are many use cases where this is needed, e.g just to let all the event handlers fire before doing something, or, if we simply add a timeout param to that function, it becomes one of the most used functions since Promises arrived,  `wait( timeout )`.

Comment: @Kaiido — It doesn't look like it, but the code the OP provided is so hypothetical and lacking in the context of a practical problem that it is hard to tell.

Comment: hum... what code did I provide? Doesn't look like what?

Comment: @Quentin In some way, if I understand correctly, if you don't have a way to execute the function code in parallel (like network requests) and you don't want to let the browser do work immediately after the function, it's pretty pointless to execute whatever code in the executor, right? Also, the first sentence clarified things a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin Just to add, about the first sentence, aren't `Promise`'s also a way to create async code? Because you can do `Promise.resolve().then(() => {//async code})`. Which makes them a way to manage async code, and create async functions?

Comment: @LearningMath — Yes, it is pointless, not promises don't create async code. The contents of the function you pass to `then()` will still be blocking.

Comment: @Quentin Hmm now I am confused. Doesn't it mean that the fuction is not executing in parallel but is still asynchronous because it returns values later in time? Your comment implies that a function to be async must be executing in parallel. Is that true or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I want to summarize what I have learned from the answers and comments from @Bergi and @Quentin. My understanding now is as follows:

An asynchronous function is characterized only by the fact that it returns immediately (may perform some synchronous operations or not, which is irrelevant), and most importantly it waits in a non-blocking manner to return a value which is used to notify its subscribers that wait to be notified when the result is ready. Additionally, the operations that the function performs, might be executed in the following manners:

1. Thread blocking, i.e as in the example I provided
2. Non-blocking, executing concurrently (network stuff, file reading)
3. Non-blocking, deferred for later, for example by `setTimeout` like in my second example

Examples for all three:

First:

```
/**
  Compute the result synchronously, return immediately, and resolve with a value later, calling the callback
*/
function first(cb) {
 // synchronous code
 value = 0;
 setTimeout(() => cb(value), 0) 
}
```

Also another example for this one:

```
/*
Immediately resolve the promise synchronously, and then call the callback with value
*/
function first(){
 const value = 0;
 return Promise.resolve(value);
}

first().then((value) => {})
```

Second:

```
function second() {
  return Promise.resolve(
    fetch('some url'))
    .then(response => response.json())
}
```

Third:

```
/*
 Return immediately, perform the function code later, and resolve with a value later
*/
function third() {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   // the function code
   if (condition) resolve()
   else reject()
  }, 0)
  
 })
```

The main feature, all return immediately, delivering results to the callback/s or resolving in a non-blocking manner.

Feel free to correct me, I try to understand it as best as I can. Thank you.